# tomcat 6 stability issue on windows 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc, jvm

i have an internal workflow web-based app.  it was running fine at about 6 requests per second.  i was using jvm 1.6, tomcat 6, windows 2003, sqlserver 2005.  tomcat was located on the same VM as sqlserver.  no clustering.

then there was a port to sqlserver 2012, and the web app moved to jvm 1.8, still tomcat 6, and upgrade jdbc driver from jtds 1.2.1 to 1.3.1 to support the new sqlserver version.  and tomcat moved to its own vm.

and what happened is that after the upgrades (above) once a week the network traffic on the tomcat VM drops to 0, CPU goes to 60% and tomcat is unresponsive until tomcat gets restarted, then it runs OK for another week.

we tried downgrading to jvm 1.7, back to 1.6 and jtds 1.3.1 to microsoft jdbc driver.  no improvement.  what i want to try next is to put tomcat 6 on its own PC, windows 2003 and monitor it because i am concerned about the VM configuration/ network configuration causing this problem.  thoughts?

thanks!

tom

Comment: Have you profiled your application?

Comment: No I have not.  I am monitoring the OS (perfmon) and the java process/JVM that tomcat is running in (task manager).  And I can see that there are no memory or CPU or disk issues until bam -- network traffic on the VM goes to 0 and CPU pegs at 60% until tomcat 6 windows service is restarted.  If you still think that a profile makes sense, what profiler would you use?  What would you look for?  E.g. memory management is stable....

Comment: While the application is behaving as described, take a few thread dumps of the application 5-10 seconds apart and then compare them, to see what the JVM is spending its time doing. It's possible that GC activity is killing you, but it's not very likely for long periods at a time.

Comment: thanks ))  waiting for the problem to happen again.  will update.....